# Is this declaration correct ? --- virtual void AcquireLockExclusive() RTC_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;

Tags: c++, webrtc

I am reading webrtc src. I find this snippet in C++:

```
class RTC_LOCKABLE RWLockWrapper {
 public:
  static RWLockWrapper* CreateRWLock();
  virtual ~RWLockWrapper() {}

  virtual void AcquireLockExclusive() RTC_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;
  virtual void ReleaseLockExclusive() RTC_UNLOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;

  virtual void AcquireLockShared() RTC_SHARED_LOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;
  virtual void ReleaseLockShared() RTC_UNLOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;
};
```

there seem to be two functions in one line:
`virtual void AcquireLockExclusive() RTC_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_FUNCTION() = 0;`
Is it syntactically correct?

Comment: `Is it syntactically correct?` Well, it's a compiler extension, so it's correct for that compiler.

Answer (score 0):

RTC_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_FUNCTION() is a preprocessor macro, possibly declaring cv-attributes.